# "Can't update table in stored function/trigger" with "DELETE AFTER UPDATE on condition" trigger

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

My current code for the trigger is:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER checkStock
    AFTER UPDATE ON product_size
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.stock < 1 THEN
        DELETE FROM product_size WHERE Product_ID = old.Product_ID AND Size_ID = old.Size_ID;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

(The table product_size has three columns: Product_ID, Size_ID and stock)

What I'm trying to do is make it so that when someone buys an item, and the stock goes to less than 1, the product should be deleted. But if I try a simple Update statement like:

```
UPDATE product_size SET stock = 0 WHERE Size_ID = 0 AND Product_ID = 9
```

I keep getting this error:

> Can't update table 'product_size' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Does anybody know what I could change about the statement, so that it would work? I have tried looking it up, but I couldn't find a solution for this DELETE AFTER UPDATE trigger.

Comment: 'Does anybody know what I could change about the statement, so that it would work? ' - can never work for the reason shown in the error message..

Comment: @P.Salmon Is there no way to check a value on an updated row in MySql and delete them if the condition is true, in a trigger then?

Comment: No, it is not possible to do this from a trigger in mysql.

Comment: Use a stored procedure to update the table or perform the deletion

Comment: Ahh.. okay. Thanks for the help everyone. Will look into stored procedures!

Comment: But don't waste your time calling a procedure from a trigger, mysql is wise to that (attempted) dodge.

Comment: To be specific, the issue you are having is that MySQL does not allow triggers to modify the contents of any table involved in the query that initiated the trigger (other than the specific row being operated on in BEFORE triggers). This necessarily means the table the trigger is ON will always be restricted, but may extend to commonly associated tables, such as an update like `UPDATE a INNER JOIN c ON a.id = c.a_id SET a.x = c.y` will not allow an `ON a` trigger to modify the data in `c`.